# Making A Dynamic HTML Page to Redirect to A URL Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I need to make A Dynamic HTML Page to Redirect to A URL Using JavaScript.
As a beginner, i need your help...
What i want to do is to redirect to a url through a html page.
For example: suppose a page address is `www.example.com/pages.html?http://yahoo.com/news` so this `pages.html` page in this case will redirect a user to yahoo.com/news ....
I know how to do this with PHP but i cant understand how i should do it with javascript and HTML . any idea? Thanks

Comment: is that a query string? or is that the format of url?

Comment: location.href = location.href.split("?")[1];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
 function Redirect(){
  var current = window.location.href;
  var exclude = current.indexOf('?');
  window.location = current.substr(exclude + 1);
 }
 setTimeout("Redirect()",5000);
```

Comment: thanks its OK now :) wonder is there any variables like `sleep(5);` which is possible in php to set timers . can i do like this with javascript, so people will redirect to that url after 5 seconds! thanks

Comment: @itistg - edited to include a 5 second pause before redirection

Comment: thanks, its works perfectly now!! by the way i was trying with `setTimeout("countdown()", 5000)` ..... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href="new-url.html";` to go to a URL with JavaScript.

To parse the URL, use `var theURL=window.location.href.split("?")[1];`

Answer (score 0):

```
location.href = location.href.split("?")[1];
```